# Content shows up when clicked on the link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am generating content when clicking on the img a href link similar to this site on the navigation button similar to this site http://www.google.com.ph/nexus/.

I've tried using :after and content: pseudo elements but the content can only show a link. How would I show a div when I clicked on the link.

I would like to generate a div when I clicked on the navigation icon similar to this site http://www.google.com.ph/nexus/. my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/. How would I go about achieving this. I want to generate content through a particular div instead of a link. Any help would be appreciated.

here is my html

```
<div id="center">
    <ul>
<li>    
    <p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com.ph/nexus/">
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/menu-24-24.png">
    </a>
</li>

</div>
</html>
```

here is the design css

```
ul li
{
    list-style:none;
}
li a
{
    content:url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/menu-24-24.png");
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `</p>` in your html

Comment: Is the behavior you're trying to duplicate the dropdown nav menu on the Nexus page, or something else? I'm not clear yet on your goal.

Comment: Also, your fiddle link goes to the site root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for something like this.

You might want to take a look and invent into Twitter bootstrap modalbox

[Modalbox](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)